# How to display data from specific table row columns in the database with MySQLI vs MySQL

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I am still really new to MySQL and even newer to MySQLI. I am trying to update my website with MySQLI and I can't seem to fix this last issue.

My website is a single page site with 50 categories on the page. Each category has a category title. I have a table in the database with all 50 category titles and id's. I was using MySQL/PHP to display each category title at the top of each category by choosing the row and column specifically. Here is my code..

The Query:

```
$query_meta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `categories`", $connection);
    if (!$query_meta) {
        die("Connection Failed: " . mysql_error());
    }

$meta_query_result = array();

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_meta) ) {
    $meta_query_result[$row['id']] = array('url' => $row['url'], 'name' => $row['name'], 'title' => $row['title']);
}
```

The Echo Statement:

```
<h2><?php echo $meta_query_result[1]['name']; ?></h2>   
<h6><?php echo $meta_query_result[1]['title']; ?></h6>
```

This allows me to choose the row and the column I want to display.

How can I redo this in MySQLI? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) http://ee1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php 2) http://ee1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php 3) http://ee1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Basically add `i`'s to all your functions and switch your connection parameter to come first instead of after in `mysql_`

Comment: I'm sorry I was unable to understand how to get those references to work in the way I need them too. The third one you posted allows me to display the first record in the table but how can I use it to choose which column/row i want to display?

Comment: @user2526699 same way as you are doing it your code. Fill array with data you need and after by index dispaly whay you want or just add `WHERE id = 1` in your query, where 1 is category id.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the connection on the opposite side with mysqli.

so //  `mysql_query($q, $db_connnect);` // becomes // `mysqli_query($db_connnect, $q);`

Answer (score 0):

Of course you should read [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php), because it looks the same (on first glance) as mysql but has little difference...

Next example should be good for you:

```
<?php

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root');
if ($db->connect_errno) {
    echo 'Connect failed: '.$db->connect_error;
    exit();
}
$db->select_db('test');
$cursor = $db->query('SELECT * FROM categories');
if ($db->error) {
    echo $db->error.PHP_EOL;
}
$meta_query_result = [];
while($row = $cursor->fetch_assoc()){
    $meta_query_result[$row['id']] = [
        'url' => $row['url'],
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'title' => $row['title'],
    ];
}
$cursor->close();
```

*Notice:And remember that mysql_query is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, use PDO instead.*